# How to set video MIME-type for VideoJs in IIS Express / Webmatrix

Tags: html5-video, webmatrix, iis-express

I'm developing a .NET site which is running locally on IIS Express through WebMatrix.  The site contains a VideoJS script which basically plays HTML5 video.  The video which has been loaded in is .mov format.  The player renders and the set up is all working except that when I click 'play' I get an error "200 Stream Not Found Netstream.Play.Stream not found".  I believe this is because the server doesn't know how to handle this format of video.

So, question is, using IIS Express, how do I get it to recognise this video format?

Thanks!

Comment: My issue actually was different - although the error message was ambigous.  The error was that the filepath needed to be absolute for the flash version, not relative.  Regarding flash mime-types and how to set this in IIS Express, I'm still curious to know, in case it's a requirement to add custom mime-types into IIS Express in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me out.
http://www.tomasmcguinness.com/2011/07/06/adding-support-for-svg-to-iis-express/

Answer (score 0):

.mov mimemap is already exists in the default IIS Express configuration. Does this application works in in-box IIS?

Comment: Thanks @vikomall.  It actually works okay in Chrome, but not Firefox.  It seems to be that Firefox is serving the video through FlowPlayer which is flash based, whereas Chrome is serving it as proper HTML5 video, which is fine.  I'm not sure what format this is actually being served in then in the case of Firefox (can Flash serve .mov content!?)  So I think the original question still stands but it's a problem with the server serving flash content rather than mov content.  Does anyone know how to configure IIS Express to stream flash video?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Firefox uses the OGG /OGV files for HMTL5 videos. You need to add that MIME Type to your server.

The MIME types is in the ISS configuration.
http://js.hosting.com/support/dedicated/iis/newmime

For Apache webserver you need to add to your .htaccess file

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm